# Apache Spark iterate DataFrame columns and apply the value transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read csv file into Spark DataFrame and infer the column names based on cvs file header:

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv("users.csv")
```

right now I need to transform column values, for example:

```
val modifedDf1 = df.withColumn("country", when(col("country") === "Italy", "[ITALY]").otherwise(col("country")))

val modifedDf2 = modifedDf1.withColumn("city", when(col("city") === "Milan", "[MILAN]").otherwise(col("city")))
```

As you may see, in order to modify the column value I need to explicitly select the column `withColumn("city"..` and then apply the condition.

Right now I need to repeat this code for each column I'd like to modify.

Is it possible to rewrite this code in order to iterate each column in `df` DataFrame and apply the following (in pseudocode):

```
df.foreachColumn {
    if (col_name == 'country')) 
        then when(col_value === "Italy", "[ITALY]").otherwise(col_value)
    else if (col_name == 'city')) 
        then when(col_value === "Milan", "[MILAN]").otherwise(col_value)
}
```

I'll appreciate the example in Scala.

**UPDATED**

This is my original df:

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|name  |email             |phone         |country      |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|Mike  |mike@example.com  |+91-9999999999|Italy        |
|Alex  |alex@example.com  |+91-9999999998|France       |
|John  |john@example.com  |+1-1111111111 |United States|
|Donald|donald@example.com|+1-2222222222 |United States|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I have the following code right now:

```
val columnsModify = df.columns.map(col).map(column => {
  val columnName = s"${column}"
  if (columnName == "country") {
    column as "[COUNTRY]"
  } else if (columnName == "email") {
    column as "(EMAIL)"
  } else {
    column as columnName
  }
})
```

which is able to iterate the DataFrame columns and change their names according to the specified conditions.

This is the output:

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|name  |(EMAIL)           |phone         |[COUNTRY]    |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|Mike  |mike@example.com  |+91-9999999999|Italy        |
|Alex  |alex@example.com  |+91-9999999998|France       |
|John  |john@example.com  |+1-1111111111 |United States|
|Donald|donald@example.com|+1-2222222222 |United States|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I also need to add the transformation logic for the column values, something like this(please see commented line below):

```
val columnsModify = df.columns.map(col).map(column => {
  val columnName = s"${column}"
  if (columnName == "country") {
    //when(column_value === "Italy", "[ITALY]").otherwise(column_value)
    column as "[COUNTRY]"
  } else if (columnName == "email") {
    column as "(EMAL)"
  } else {
    column as columnName
  }
})
```

and the expected output for this script should be:

```
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|name  |(EMAL)            |phone         |[COUNTRY]    |
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|Mike  |mike@example.com  |+91-9999999999|[ITALY]      |
|Alex  |alex@example.com  |+91-9999999998|France       |
|John  |john@example.com  |+1-1111111111 |United States|
|Donald|donald@example.com|+1-2222222222 |United States|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Please show how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val newCols = df.schema.map{
  column =>

    val colName = column.name

    colName match{
      case "country" => when(col(colName) === "Italy", "ITALY").otherwise(col(colName)).as("[COUNTRY]") 
      case "email" => col(colName).as("[EMAIL]")
      case _ => col(colName) 
    } 
}

df.select(newCols.head, newCols.tail: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize, probably I was not clear but this is not something I'm looking for. Please see, my updated question with more details.

Comment: I have updated the example above but am not sure I quite understand your problem. Do you want to auto generate your selected columns from the schema providing special logic for country and email columns?

Comment: I'd like to implement the schema-agnostic approach that will allow me to specify the transformation from the existing column names into the new column names and the same for the column values. This question is only the first part of the puzzle I'd like to solve. The rules for the column name mappings and the rules for the value transformation will be defined somewhere before this logic will take a place.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the df.selectExpr

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

 val sel2 = df.columns.map( x =>
 if(x=="country") "CASE WHEN country = 'Italy' THEN '[ITALY]' ELSE country  end as `[country]` "
 else if(x=="email") " email as `(EMAL)`"
 else x
 )

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

sel2: Array[String] = Array(name, " email as `(EMAL)`", phone, "CASE WHEN country = 'Italy' THEN '[ITALY]' ELSE country  end as `[country]` ")

scala>  df.selectExpr(sel2:_*).show
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  name|            (EMAL)|         phone|    [country]|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+
|  Mike|  mike@example.com|+91-9999999999|      [ITALY]|
|  Alex|  alex@example.com|+91-9999999998|       France|
|  John|  john@example.com| +1-1111111111|United States|
|Donald|donald@example.com| +1-2222222222|United States|
+------+------------------+--------------+-------------+


scala>
```